# ios 8 can't open URL in safari from action extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to develop simple bookmarking app with action extension. You can add bookmarks from Safari using action extension. The problem is that I can't open URL from Safari. I tried 2 approaches to do that:

```
self.extensionContext.openURL(url, completionHandler: nil)
```

If I try to open the same URL from main app using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: object.url))
```

It opens it, so URL is correct.

Also I tried to pass modified URL in completion handler of extensionContext

```
var extensionItem = NSExtensionItem()
extensionItem.attachments = [NSItemProvider(item: url, typeIdentifier: String(kUTTypeURL))]
self.extensionContext.completeRequestReturningItems([extensionItem], completionHandler: nil)
```

Both approaches lead to switching to safari, but link is not opened. Regarding second approach it seems  that Safari just doesn't handle it yet, but I have no idea why first one doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As this is about a beta version of the OS, I wonder if it's best on the Apple developer forums...?

Comment: If you're concerned about NDA, then it's not a problem anymore. http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/

Comment: Ah OK didn't realise they'd lifted NDA. Nonetheless, I wonder if there's more discussion if iOS 8 on the dev forums at the moment than here?

Comment: Not so much at the moment, quite a lot of people prefer stackoverflow. But it's good point to check both sources if you have a question.